# Should you prompt someone to ask you for mechila before Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, bein-adam-lachavero, high-holidays, rebuke-tochacha, forgiving-mechilah

If G0d forbid you have a grudge against someone (and you did not rebuke them [enough] at the time--your fault) must you/should you tell them about it before Yom Kippur so they know to ask you for mechila?

Related: [Rebuking someone for an old wrongdoing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78556/rebuking-someone-for-an-old-wrongdoing)

Comment: Why do you think maybe one should?

Comment: Can't you just forgive them independently? And if you aren't willing to forgive him, what's the point in telling him?

Comment: I don't think that rebuke ever becomes outdated. Of  course, you need to (re)evaluate the situation, as the circumstances may have changed, or the person's attitude may have changed either improved or worsened. Regardless, whether it's rebuke or otherwise, I don't see the point in "demanding" an apology from anyone under any situation. When you demand, it becomes about your own needs, and not about having the offender sense remorse over hurting you. If  he /she does apologize, frequently, they do so reluctantly, in which case, the apology is "fake".

Comment: To elaborate on @mevaqesh's comment, there's a prayer many say on Erev Rosh HaShanah and Erev Yom Kippur (at the front of the latter Artscroll Machzor) that contains a paragraph which, in essence, states that the one saying the prayer forgives all those who have hurt him, and may HaShem inspire others to do the same for him. Those who say the Yehi Ratzon in Krias Shema Al HaMitah express similar sentiments in that prayer.

Comment: Besides, if you forgive him, you're helping him out, and zakin l'adam shelo befanav.

Comment: Will you only forgive him if he asks you to?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, it's hard to forgive if someone doesn't apologize, and I'm not sure we're obliged to (although a strong argument could perhaps be made that we are)

Comment: @mevaqesh Good question. See above. An apology makes forgiveness a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that you should prompt the wrongdoer, or else wholeheartedly forgive them.

The Kizur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קלא - דיני ערב יום כפור](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0130_L2) says:

> וְאַדְרַבָּה, אִם הַחוֹטֵא אֵינוֹ מִתְעוֹרֵר לָבוֹא אֵלָיו לְבַקֵּשׁ מְחִילָה, יֵשׁ לוֹ לְהָאִישׁ הֶעָלוּב לְהַמְצִיא אֶת עַצְמוֹ לְאוֹתוֹ שֶׁחָטָא, כְּדֵי שֶׁיְבַקֵּשׁ מִמֶּנוּ מְחִילָה.

[Not only shouldn't one be difficult to appease but] rather, if the wrongdoer doesn't have any intention of coming to ask you for forgiveness, you should make yourself available to them so that he can ask you for forgiveness.

If he is not made aware of his "sin", how can he ask you for forgiveness?

Comment: Re the last sentence - I'm not disagreeing. But, could one argue *Hanistarot Lahashem Elokeinu*? What if the person died or is not around, or the person just forgot. Is the one who sin against him automatically absolved?

Comment: @DanF - See the Gemara in Chagiga 5a towards the bottom on the verse "על כל נעלם" - Gcd will [even] take you to task for inadvertently grossing out a fellow.